# PHP error: Notice: Undefined variable: pass in /home/publiqav/public_html/x.php on line 29

Tags: php

Tengo un código de una pagina que tenia hace mucho tiempo, ahora la estoy actualizando pero me ha costado mucho debido a que no se mucho de *PHP*, ojala puedan ayudarme con este error.

Les dejo parte del código.

```
<?
include ("config.php");
?><html><head>
<title>Acceso al Sistema de Administraci&oacute;n</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language=JavaScript>
<!--
function adv(){alert("Error:* * * * * * \nNO Registrado en el Sistema.\nPor Favor revise su c�digo.");}

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?
$link =mysqli_connect ("localhost", "$nubd","$password");  
?>
  
  
<?
if($pass!='' and $pass>0) //esta es la linea del problema
{
$result =mysqli_query($link,"select pass,ID_user from usuario where pass='$pass'");
$cant=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$info=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($cant==0)
{
    echo "<script language=JavaScript>
    adv();
    </script>";
}
else    
{
```

ojala puedan ayudarme gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué tan antiguo es tu código? ¿Dependías de que las variables provenientes de formularios o URL se registraran como globales? Si es el caso, entonces tienes que asignarla, por ejemplo: `$pass = $_POST['pass'];` aunque no creo que sea una solución definitiva, tienes otros problemas de lógica, porque dos o más usuarios pueden tener la misma contraseña y no estás considerando esa parte en tu código.

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: la variable `$pass` no está definida. ¿Dónde *crees* que defines esa variable para luego poder usarla? ¿De dónde debe ser tomada para ser evaluada?

Comment: se supone que pasw es el pasword que esta en la tabla usuario en la base de datos. este pasw tiene por defecto el valor 1. que se supone que yo al ingresar 1 en el formulario el codigo lo evalua y me genera algo que no esta generando.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas llamando a una variable que no tienes definida la variable `$pass`. Creo que lo que estas buscando es la variable `$password`, la cual si tienes al conectarte a MySQL. Cambia $pass a $password y debería de funcionar. Espero que te sirva

Comment: es un código de una pagina web de avisos clasificados. la cosa es que deje de usarla y el codigo php actualizo con los años. el codigo que muestro y en el donde sale el error deberia funcionar de la siguiente manera.  dentro de la base de datos en la tabla usuario hay un pasw que es 1, ese codigo es para entrar a la administracion y asi poder actualizar la contraseña o eliminar avisos etc. pero al ingresar 1 en pasw en vez de entrar me sale ese error. no se si me hago entender.